# Why using $ΔV =−∫E⋅dr$ doesn't produce the correct answer when we bring the charge from the infinity?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, conventions

Let say I use $ΔV =−∫E⋅dr $ to calculate the potential in space due to the electric field of a sphere with charge $Q$ by setting $V = 0$ at infinite.

Then $V= -∫(kq/r^2).dr  $,  Since i am bringing from infinite to a certain distance r, the displacement is opposite to the electric field. Therefore the equation becomes $V= ∫(kq/r^2)dr = -kq/r$

I know this is wrong because if i go opposite to the electric field, i should be gaining potential, yet here my potential is negative.  What did i do wrong?

Comment: Put the actual limits on the integral and it will come out right.

Comment: well if i try with a sphere like here, it wont come out fine.  it will come out exactly -kq/r which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing the limits on an integral changes the sign of the result. So, you don't need to use $-dr$ when bringing a charge from infinity inwards, since that negative sign is already implied by using infinity for the lower limit.
\begin{align}
\Delta V &= -\int_{r_1}^{r_2} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r}\\
         &= -\int_{\infty}^R \frac{kq}{r^2}dr \\
         &= -kq\int_{\infty}^R \frac{dr}{r^2}\\
         &= -kq\left[-\frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{\infty}\right]\\
         &= \frac{kq}{R}
\end{align}

Comment: So you are saying that we reversed the limits on the integral, but isnt r1 defined as the initial point and r2 the final point? So we actually didnt reversed it.  and the scalar product should still remain in the second step.

Comment: @Richard I'm saying that, even though you are going from infinity to R (in the negative direction), because r1 is the initial point and r2 is the final point, you don't need to change the sign of the integrand or of dr. The direction of the displacement is handled by putting the integration limits in the right order.